# How to make "inappropriate blocking method call" appropriate?

Tags: kotlin, okhttp, kotlin-coroutines, moshi

I am currently trying to leverage kotlin coroutines more. But I face a problem: when using moshi or okhttp inside these coroutines I get a warning:

"inappropriate blocking method call"

What is the best way to fix these? I really do not want to be inappropriate ;-)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The warning is about methods that block current thread and coroutine cannot be properly suspended. This way, you lose all benefits of coroutines and downgrade to one job per thread again.

Each case should be handled in a different way. For suspendable http calls you can use [ktor http client](https://ktor.io/clients/index.html). But sometimes there is no library for your case, so you can either write your own solution or ignore this warning.

Edit: `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` or some custom dispatcher can be used to workaround the problem. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Ignoring the warning is almost never the right thing, you can at least run the blocking code in `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`.

Comment: if you run the blocking code with `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` then it isn't blocking anymore and the warning isn't correct, right?

Comment: @noloman good question because "at least" assumes knowledge that somebody who is asking this question does not have. Still the warning does not go away when you introduce this wrapper.

Comment: @noloman A blocking call is still a blocking call but `Dispatchers.IO` can tolerate blocking calls because unlike `Dispatchers.Default` it can create as many threads as it needs. Other dispatchers could run out of threads if they all get locked up by blocking calls.

Comment: @Tenfour04 so if we wrap the code in `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` then the warning is incorrect? AndroidStudio still displays it for me, unless I drop the suspend and use `runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO)` instead.

Comment: @Stachu There are some false positives bug reports like this (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-39684) so that's possible. But there are blocking calls that intentionally trigger the warning even for Dispatchers.IO, such as `Thread.sleep()`, which is a code smell in any place in a coroutine.

Comment: @Tenfour04, [Dispatchers.IO](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html) also has a limit of 64 threads or the number of cores (whichever is larger).

Comment: adding ```withContext(Dispatchers....)```  did not remove the warning

Comment: Dispatchers.IO not works in my case , IOUtils.toByteArray & contentResolver.openInputStream

Comment: So what is the correct answer? Just wrap the blocking code with `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` and ignore the warning?

Comment: try wrap the code here

                        kotlin.runCatching {
                                // your code here
                        }

Comment: This was acknowledged as an overeager inspection. Dispatchers.IO is the right way to do this, but it's hard to prove work back up the context path and determine whether it's running in safe context. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-838

Comment: It is fixed as of IntelliJ 2022.1. It is even a suggestion from the editor to use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`

Comment: I'm running `Android Studio 2021.1.1 Patch 3
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8309675, on March 16, 2022`, and now a statement like `FileInputStream(File("dummy.txt"))` is flagged even inside `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`

Comment: Just adding withContext(Dispatchers.IO) will not help if you are calling Java blocking methods like BufferedReader.readLine(). In these cases you will still get the warning.

Comment: Any final Answer Here???

Comment: @user1575326 Can you please specify in which documentation they recommend it? Why people simply post their opinions whithout any reference and call it "This is how it must be done"?!

Comment: @MonteCreasor can you explain a bit more about why calling a java blocking method or any other blocking method which is not suspendable on Dispatchers.IO is a problem?

Comment: @Sarthak_ssg5 I think there are 2 issues. One is that where possible, you should use suspendable functions so that the coroutine framework will retain control of the calling thread to run other coroutines as it sees fit. The other reason is that, as someone else pointed out) suspendable functions/methods play nicely with coroutine cancellation.

Answer (score 87):

Exceptions can occur that's why it shows this warning. Use `runCatching{}`. It catches any Throwable exception that was thrown from the block function execution and encapsulating it as a failure.

For Example:

```
 CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
         runCatching{
               makeHttpRequest(URL(downloadLocation))
         }
}
```

Comment: This works but still looks like a hack or an exploit to circumvent Kotlin Plugin's buggy detection of inappropriate blocking calls. Because essentially what this method does is just wrap the problematic call in a `try ... catch` block which somehow makes it invisible to the inspection.

Comment: It worked for me in both FileInputStream and FileOutputStream modes. Thanks

Comment: The weird thing is that `try ... catch` is not the same as `runCatching`. Only `runCatching` will hide the error, even though the 2 are the same.

Comment: runCatching does silence the warning, but doesn't tackle the issue highlighted by the warning. It's better to add suppression annotation to the method, than using runCatching ( @Suppress("BlockingMethodInNonBlockingContext") )

Answer (score 71):

You also get this warning when calling a suspending function that is annotated with `@Throws(IOException::class)` (Kotlin 1.3.61). Not sure if that is intended or not. Anyway, you can suppress this warning by removing that annotation or changing it to `Exception` class.

Comment: Let's call it suppressing, not fixing :) I suppose, static analyzer highlights it because the method which throws IOException is usually blocking and takes some valuable time to finish.

Comment: I found this explanation about IOException helpful: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/warning-inappropriate-blocking-method-call-with-coroutines-how-to-fix/16903/2

Comment: For me, I found it's `InterruptedException::class` will cause the warning.

Answer (score 31):

**Wrap** the *"inappropriate blocking method call"* **code** in **another context** using **`withContext`**.

That is to say (for example):

If you are doing a read/write blocking method call:

```
val objects = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { dao.getAll() }
```

If you are performing a blocking network request (using Retrofit):

```
val response = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { call.execute() }
```

Or if you are performing a CPU intensive blocking task:

```
val sortedUsers = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { users.sortByName() }
```

This will suspend the current coroutine, then execute the *"inappropriate blocking call"* on a different thread (from either the `Dispatchers.IO` or `Dispatchers.Default` pools), thereby **not blocking** the thread your coroutine is executing on.

Comment: I don't get it. I tried using Dispatchers.IO and it still shows a warning. I added `Thread.sleep` to simulate long waiting there. I want to be able to let it be cancelled via any means that I could using threads (interruptions and checking if it's cancelled).

Comment: This problem is related to Kotlin coroutines (asynchronous programming). If you use `Thread.sleep`, you are directly manipulating the underlying (Java architecture) thread. Use the `suspendCoroutine` function inside a coroutine scope to make the coroutine wait for a job to finish, while the underlying thread is free to continue executing other coroutines.

Comment: Since Thread.sleep is a valid case of functions (can be done in functions that I call, for example, which I have no control of what they have inside), I can't replace it.

Comment: Can you share the code that gives the warning?

Comment: Adding the above withContext does not work either

Comment: What specific function call in what library results in the generation of the warning?

Answer (score 20):

If you do choose to suppress like some of the answers suggest, use

`@Suppress("BlockingMethodInNonBlockingContext")`

Comment: I use a helper class that runs code in `Dispatchers.IO`. Despite of this it shows the warning in `val response = someMethod().execute` and `response.body()?.string()`. So, I just suppress the warning.

Comment: Why would someone in their right mind suppress such a warning? This is more than a warning. This means you just crippled the whole coroutine arcitecture and better not use it.

Comment: @Farid One example: calling readLine() in a coroutine when reading from local csv file is ok, but will provide this warning and it can be locally suppressed

Comment: No, it is not okay. What if you have multiple coroutines reading files from local? If any coroutine hits `runBlocking` then the whole thread will be blocked. Meaning other coroutines will wait until `runBlocking` finishes which is against the purpose of coroutines

Comment: @Farid. nope doesn't happen, it's been tested

Comment: @seekingStillness What do you mean by no? It is even in official documentation (https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html)which reads "This function should not be used from coroutine". Do you mind sharing your "tests" that actually disprove the documentation?

Answer (score 12):

I'm using Android Studio 4.1, and the warning shows when I use `Moshi` or manipulate `File`. Wrapping the code in a `withContext` doesn't help even if I'm sure about what I'm doing.

I recently found out that moving **the tiny code that warns** into a standard method without `suspend` like `fun action() {...}` can remove the warning. This is ugly since it simply hides the warning.

Update: From my personal experience, it appears suppressing the warning or runBlocking is more straightforward.

Update2: After upgrading to Android Studio Flamingo(AGP 8), some warnings disappear; for those who don't, wrapping code in a `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` sometimes remove the warning. A related explanation: https://youtu.be/zluKcazgkV4?t=2400

Comment: Don't use `runBLocking` in your production code at all. Someone will use it in coroutines and everything will be clocked and become a mess. https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html

Answer (score 2):

It looks like encasing the call in `kotlin.runCatching()` resolves the warning, not sure why though... Because as previous answer about runCatching states it's not due to the exception throwing since even try{} catch doesn't resolve the issue, could be some buggy detection issue...
I ended up using the below for now...

```
val result = kotlin.runCatching {
     OldJavaLib.blockingCallThatThrowsAnException()
}
if (result.isSuccess) {
      print("success is on your side")
} else {
      print("one failure is never the end")
}
```

Comment: runCatching does silence the warning, but doesn't tackle the issue highlighted by the warning. It's better to add suppression annotation to the method, than using runCatching ( @Suppress("BlockingMethodInNonBlockingContext") )

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to wrap blocking code via `suspend fun kotlinx.coroutines.runInterruptible`.
Without it, **the blocking code won't be interrupted**, when coroutine's job gets cancelled.

It suppressed compile warning and blocking code will throw `InterruptedException` on cancellation

```
val job = launch {
  runInterruptible(Dispatchers.IO) {
    Thread.sleep(500) // example blocking code
  }
}

job.cancelAndJoin() // Cause will be 'java.lang.InterruptedException'
```

https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-interruptible.html

[How to convert Java blocking function into cancellable suspend function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58832714/2075875)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you suspend your Coroutine, run your blocking method in a thread, and resume it on result. This will also handle exceptions, so your app won't crash.

```
suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    thread {
        try {
            doHttpRequest(URL(...)) {
                continuation.resume(it)
            }
        }
        catch (t: Throwable) {
            continuation.resumeWithException(t)
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: The intended way to do it is to use `witchContext(Dispatchers.IO)`. I leave this response here in case someone finds this approach useful.

Comment: Which is more expensive: create a new thread or block one of the pool of coroutines?

Answer (score -2):

I ran into the same issue today, here goes the solution worked for me. Hope it helps!

```
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

        val call = client.newCall(request)
        call.enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                print("Internet access, 4G, Wifi, DNS, etc failed")
            }
    
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful) {
                    print("Server accepted!")
                } else {
                    print("Server failed!")
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Keep in mind this callbacks are consumed only once. You can't use it into other threads.

Answer (score -7):

I used dispatchers as launch arguments:

```
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // Do background work
        
        // Back to main thread
        launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "SUCCESS!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very bad idea. You're passing context into an uncontrolled coroutine. 
You should avoid using GlobalScope
https://elizarov.medium.com/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc

Comment: It works and answers the question, there are always better ways to do things depending on the use case, in my case I have a relatively small one activity app.

Comment: You could have posted the "better" answer instead of "it works and answers question" type of answer. There are lots of new people to this concept and you are intentionally misleading them

Comment: @EdgarKhimich I read that blog and attempted in my code. Android Studio raise the warning point in the original question. I also understood the approach pointed in the blog is in the case you "stack" several threads at one point. I am not sure if other GlobalScope in other parts of the code would have this issue as well.