# Android and Kotlin coroutines: inappropriate blocking method call

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have the following class:

```
class Repository(
    private val assetManager: AssetManager,
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
) {
    suspend fun fetchHeritagesList(): HeritageResponse = withContext(ioDispatcher) {
        try {
            // TODO Blocking method call?
            val bufferReader = assetManager.open("heritages.json").bufferedReader()
...
```

and I'm wondering why do I get a warning in the `open("heritages.json")` saying `Innapropriate blocking method call`? isn't the `withContext(ioDispatcher)` fixing that?

Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: It's a bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-838

Answer (score 30, accepted):

IntelliJ inspection that looks for blocking calls inside suspendable functions isn't powerful enough to see through a level of indirection between `Dispatchers.IO` and its usage in `withContext`. Here's a minimal reproducer of the issue:

```
class IoTest {
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO

    suspend fun indirectRef() = withContext(ioDispatcher) {
        FileInputStream(File("dummy.txt")) // Flagged as inappropriate blocking call
    }

    suspend fun directRef() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        FileInputStream(File("dummy.txt")) // Not flagged
    }
}
```

However, unlike in my case, your `ioDispatcher` is exposed for injection through the constructor so you could just as easily supply `Dispatchers.Main` instead of it, and that *would* constitute inappropriate blocking.

Unfortunately I haven't yet heard of any way to formally specify the contract of a dispatcher as "tolerating blocking calls", so that you could enforce it in the constructor.

There is already a similar issue open on [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-227359).

**EDIT:** As of the build from March 16, 2022, there seems to be a regression that flags IO calls even inside a `withContext(IO)`.

Comment: The second one actually is flagged: https://i.imgur.com/UdfcQ6y.png

Comment: I just showed you it is. Maybe you use a newer version of the IDE. I use "Android Studio 4.2 Beta 4
Build #AI-202.7660.26.42.7094744, built on January 21, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174 amd64"

Comment: Both are flagged here as well, on Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8512546.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680028/how-to-make-inappropriate-blocking-method-call-appropriate

Comment: At first glance this looks like a regression. I'm running `Android Studio 2021.1.1 Patch 3 Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8309675 on March 16, 2022`, and now a statement like `FileInputStream(File("dummy.txt"))` is flagged even inside `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`

Answer (score 0):

Code below can hang, because of blocking IO:

```
class MyService(assetManager: AssetManager) {
   private val repo = Repository(assetManager, newFixedThreadPoolContext(nThreads: 1, name: "SO QA"))

   suspend fun read(): HeritageResponse {
      return fetchHeritagesList(); // <-- please note, that we replaced IO dispatcher to single-threaded one
   }
}
```