# Kotlin - "Inappropriate Block Method Call" when making Bluetooth Connection inside Coroutine

Tags: android, bluetooth, kotlin-coroutines

I am getting a warning when I try to make a BT connection inside a coroutine.

I've checked [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680028/how-to-make-inappropriate-blocking-method-call-appropriate), but it was only abstract theorycrafting and no material code. One of the answers there mentioned that the warning in the title should be dealt in a case-by-case basis, so here is my case. Does anyone know how I can resolve the warning? Thanks!

```
fun initSocket() = runBlocking {
    try {
        mSocket = // Assume socket is initialized correctly. Not relevant here
        mSocket.connect() // "Inapproprite Blocking Method Call"
        mOutputStream = mSocket.outputStream
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error establishing Socket Connection...")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't actually contain any suspendable function calls. Simply remove `runBlocking` and you'll have the same blocking behavior that you have now.

If, by any chance, you do have some suspendable calls which you removed from your example as "irrelevant", then you should move the blocking call outside `runBlocking` and wrap only those suspendable calls in it.

Answer (score 1):

You are running entire thing inside `runBlocking`, which [blocks the thread](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html) until it finishes. By the looks of it, you are calling it from the main thread, which is not allowed to make blocking calls - hence the error.

Instead of `runBlocking`, rather make `suspend` function using `Dispathers.IO`, to offload the connecting to an IO thread to avoid blocking main thread.

```
suspend fun initSocket() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { ... }
```

Comment: The warning is given not for `runBlocking` but for `mSocket.connect()`. `runBlocking` occurs within a plain, non-suspendable function so there is nothing inappropriate about it.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing even when switching context to IO running code related to blocking file access.