# How to get body from a server response with code 400 in Kotlin with coroutine and retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I have a xampp server connected to my android app.
When I perform an api call, it would return either a response code 200 or a response code 400.
If the response code is 200, I'm able to get the body of the response.

Here is the response body:

```
{"message": "User was created."}
```

However, I'm unable to get the response body when the code is 400.

It is null.

This is my interface:

```
@POST("api/user/createUser.php")
suspend fun register(@Body details : JsonObject) : Response<JsonElement>
```

This is how I call it:

```
val service = Server.ApiClient.createService(ServerInterface::class.java)
        
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

            try {
                val response = service.register(details)
                Log.wtf("Message",response.body().toString())
            }
            catch (e : Exception){
                Log.wtf("Error",e.message)
            }
        }
```

Here is the log :

Response code 200:

```
E/Message: {"message":"User was created."}
```

Response code 400:

```
E/Message: null
```

Does anybody know how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, retrofit handles response codes outside 200-399 range as errors, so the message should be available using `response.errorBody()` instead of `response.body()`.

Comment: When I call .toString() on the `response.errorBody()` ,  the String is like this : `okhttp3.ResponseBody$Companion$asResponseBody$1@559aed4`

Comment: @BinishMathew that's because `errorBody()` returns an object of type `ResponseBody`. You can call the [`string()`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-response-body/string/) method on it to get the response body as a String: `response.errorBody().string()`

Comment: That worked. Thanks @user2340612 but the string() is flagged as  `Inappropriate blocking method call` . What does that mean ?

Comment: Basically that warning is saying that the method may potentially block the thread by reading the entire response body into memory, vanishing the potential benefit of coroutines. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680028/how-to-make-inappropriate-blocking-method-call-appropriate) you may find more info