# Kotlin Coroutine launch{} vs launch{ withContext{} }

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

My Android app need to do some file read/write in background (inside a Service), first I use:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    val fos = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE)
    val oos = ObjectOutputStream(fos)
    oos.writeObject(myObj)
    oos.close()
}
```

Every single line inside the block has a warning: "Inappropriate blocking method call"

After search the problem, I think I understand 80% of it. So basically most Coroutine only has 1 thread, if it is blocked, that coroutine will have no thread to do other job. To fix this, we should wrap it inside `withContext` like this:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val fos = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE)
        val oos = ObjectOutputStream(fos)
        oos.writeObject(myObj)
        oos.close()
    }
}
```

Android Studio still shows the warning. [The post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680028/how-to-make-inappropriate-blocking-method-call-appropriate) say it is just a bug in Android Studio, and this solution is fine.

What I don't understand is, `withContext` is still run on `Dispatchers.IO`. From the `launch` block, it may seem like non-blocking, but if `Dispatchers.IO` only has 1 thread and the `withContext` block is run on that thread, then that thread is still blocked isn't it?

I also learned `Dispatchers.IO` actually has virtually infinite threads, it just create a new one when needed. So the `withContext` actually is not blocking, but if this is true, why do we need the `withContext` block? The first code won't have any problem if `Dispatchers.IO` can create thread when needed thus will never be blocked, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug with the warning. Lint can't detect what Dispatcher the scope is using, and I suppose they just assume that you're using a scope whose context uses `Dispatchers.Main`, since that is the most common.

Your CoroutineScope (pseudo-)constructor has a context with `Dispatchers.IO`, so `launch` inherits that context if it doesn't modify it, so your launched coroutine also uses `Dispatchers.IO`. So, your `withContext` block is redundant.

Workaround would be to specify the dispatcher when launching:

```
CoroutineScope(Job()).launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val fos = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE)
    val oos = ObjectOutputStream(fos)
    oos.writeObject(myObj)
    oos.close()
}
```

Also, your statement:

> So basically most Coroutine only has 1 thread, if it is blocked, that coroutine will have no thread to do other job.

is misleading. A coroutine doesn't have threads, a Dispatcher does. And some Dispatchers have many threads.

Comment: Is it actually a filed bug, or just a limitation of the linter?

Comment: @Jolley71717, don't know. I never dug any deeper. My answer also fails to mention that you probably shouldn't be creating an impromptu CoroutineScope to launch a coroutine.

Comment: Yeah, I later decided to pass the scope into the main context and let it be inherited

Answer (score 6):

It seems there's indeed a bug in Android Studio. The following code shows no warnings for me:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val fos = context.openFileOutput("", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val oos = ObjectOutputStream(fos)
    oos.writeObject(myObj)
    oos.close()
}
```

You should also know that between this code and the two you shared, there's is virtually no difference in behavior. In all three cases the code will be executed on the IO thread.

- `CoroutineScope(context)`
- `launch(context)`
- `withContext(context`

All these methods just specify the coroutine context. By default `launch` uses the coroutine scope context, but you can change that either as I did above or by using `withContext`.

> So basically most Coroutine only has 1 thread, if it is blocked, that coroutine will have no thread to do other job.

`Dispatchers.IO` actually defaults to 64 threads.