# Geocoder Inappropriate blocking method call

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

[getFromLocation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder#getFromLocation(double,%20double,%20int)) method in [Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder) is showing `Inappropriate blocking method call` warning even though I am calling it on non-main thread as shown below.

I looked other posts including [How to make "inappropriate blocking method call" appropriate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680028/how-to-make-inappropriate-blocking-method-call-appropriate) and the answer is that it's false positive warning. I want to make sure if the answer is the same for Geocoder. Is it safe to ignore this warning?

**Geocoder** to get address with Kotlin coroutine:

```
    private suspend fun getAddress(): String = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val location = (activity as MainActivity).currentLoc
        location ?: return@withContext "location not found, try again"

        // gets full address given
        return@withContext try {
            Geocoder(requireContext(), Locale.getDefault()).getFromLocation(
                location.latitude, location.longitude, 1
            ).first().getAddressLine(0).removeSuffix(", USA")

        } catch (ioException: IOException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getAddress error -------------------------------- ", ioException)
            "location not found, try again"
        }
    }
```

Calling **getAddress()** method:

```
  lifecycleScope.launch {
        val result = getAddress()
```