# InetAddress.getByName("...") Inappropriate blocking method call

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I have this function:

```
private suspend fun sendHandshakeAnswer(websocket: DefaultWebSocketServerSession): SocketSession? {
    val dbSession = SessionManager.startSession(
        user,
        InetAddress.getByName(websocket.call.request.origin.remoteHost),
        fingerprint,
        videocard
    )
}
```

How do I make a call to this function as required by idea?

Comment: Wrap the `InetAddress.getByName` call in `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { }`.

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58684320/13963150 you can find a good explanation of this inspection message.